# ExtJS - filefield - select another file after submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, filefield

I'm working on an application for uploading files by using an ajax call using ExtJS - filefield component. I'm able to send the file without problems, but sometimes the server return an exception saying that I need to chose another file so I need to re-select another file from the filefield. However, when I already did the first ajax call, the filefield control doesn't let me to pick a new file. I click on select but the button does not work. Any idea why?

Thanks,

Comment: You'd better provided some code and specified the version of ExtJS. The catch is, behaviour of filefield control significantly changed between 4.x and 6.x version. In 4.x when a user submits a form with a filefield, it is cleared - in other words unlike other fields, it was impossible to submit the filefield twice. In more modern versions this behaviour changed. So, it all depends on code you have and on version you have.

Comment: I didn't put some code because I don't think it's going to help. but you mentioned something interesting that I didn't know. I'm using Ext 4 actually so it means that there is no way to submit a form more than once? Do you know if there is any trick in order to do that?

Comment: Yes, if you are using ExtJS 4, it is impossible to submit it twice in case it contains filefields. I've faced this problem myself and tried dozens of ugly hacks. Finally, I had to turn to a custom filefield.

Comment: I understand. I think I will have to do the same. Thanks!

Comment: No, you can submit the form twice but the filefield will be cleared so you would have to select a file again. Also, this clearing happens in 4.x, 5.x and 6.x, go ahead and try this fiddle on different versions: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1261 The form submit will always fail. I cannot reproduce any error when clicking on the button after several tries.

Comment: My problem is a bit different, I don't do any form.submit call, I do an Ext.Ajax.request call. Since I need to pass a form in order to send the files to my rest service, I build the domForm in the fly by using Ext.DomHelper.

Actually, I can perform the ajax call many times, but after the first one, I cannot select other file. The select button of the filefield component stop working; I click it and nothing happens